# Ommiting $ex variable in try-catch block

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

```
try {           

} catch (\Exception $ex) {

}
```

In my sample use case, I don't need any information from `$ex` when `\Exception` is catched. I just need to do some stuff when `\Exception` is catched. I need nothing from `$ex`.

Now ommiting `$ex` causes syntax error, leaving it usued makes my IDE (Netbeans) throw a warning.

Any way to omit `$ex` other than `$ex = '';`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't omit the hinted argument `\Exception $ex` from the `catch` statement, because the block needs to know what type of Exception it's there to deal with, even if your code doesn't care.

You don't, however, need to refer to it at all in the catch block. If the NetBeans warning hint about the unused variable is really bothering you, you can always silence all hints of that class by going to

1. Tools -> Options
2. "Editor" tab
3. "Hints" sub-tab
4. Language: PHP
5. Uncheck "Unused Variables" in list

(Of course then you won't see warnings if you have other unused variables, but if you just want the hints not to be Warnings, you can always change the "Show as:" setting to "info" instead.)

Comment: Note: I care about what type of Exception to deal with just not the contents of `$ex`.

Comment: The situation is the same for each `catch` statement you use: the variable must be named in the statement, but doesn't need to be used within the block.

Answer (score 1):

In php there is way of handling error. Because of that catch expect to have store exception. So you have to provide `$ex`. But you can leave empty inside catch in your case. 
To remember this is the syntax.

```
try {
 // run your code here
}
catch (exception $e) {
 //code to handle the exception
}
finally {
 //optional code that always runs
}
```